# How to Migrate from Plain Entities to Self-Tracking Entities?

Tags: c#, .net, orm, entity-framework-4

I'm working in a project that uses .NET Entity Framework 4 with EntityObjects. Since we have found that we need to evolve into self-tracking entities for the remaining modules that haven't been implemented, I want to ask this:

1) Can we delete the existent plain entities and regenerate self-tracking entities from the database without modifying our currently written code using them?

2) If the answer of 1) is 'yes', is that easily done? How would you proceed to migrate from the first scheme to the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the namespces of your existing POCO classes to the one you expect EF will generate and so that your references will be updated.Then delete old POCO classes and generate EF classesThen compile your solution

Answer (score 0):

By plain entities i presume you mean POCO's. You probably need to delete the POCO classes u wrote or generated and set the build action of the edmx file to EntityDeploy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm... I wasn't asking about POCOs. You made me notice that I have to rewrite the question...

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove any old T4 you may have used (if you used POCO T4), and add new self tracking POCO T4 from your model.
It should be enough to work.

Comment: And apps behavior remains the same?... we do not have to change any line in C# except to use the trackable entities facilities?

Comment: You shouldn't have to... If you didn't play with object state entries. The whole point of self tracking entities is to manage object states, so if you did some state management yourself, it could get obsolete.